# Magento 2 - LESS debuging

Tags: magento2, template, theme, less-css

I have read [Styles debugging guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html#css_exception) for M2 and can't seem to find the correct way to start debugging LESS. I have setup Grunt and browser to show original sources for less. But the original source shows the following path:

```
pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_EN/css/source/lib/module.less
```

Instead of

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_module/web/css/source/module.less
```

Did I forget to configure something via Grunt? I have followed the guide step by step.

Comment: I have not been able to get this working correctly either, but the goal is to have the browser read your map file that is generated here: `/pub/static/frontend/{{vendor}}/{{theme}}/en_US/css/styles-l.css.map`
This map will tell you where styles are being pulled from. Hope this helps to track down a solution.

Answer (score 1):

`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_module/web/css/source/module.less` is the place where you can change the layout.

`pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_EN/css/source/lib/module.less` are the precompiled files performed by the platform.

any change in `pub/static` will be erased by the application when changes files. stick to web/css/source and in `lib/css`

brgds